# ionic html5 select/keypad open, scroll the view and tab to upward and create empty space after tab on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, html, ionic-v1

I am using ionic v1 with angularJS and I have ion tabs:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <!-- Home Tab -->
  <ion-tab icon-off="ion-home" icon-on="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-home"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Calendar Tab -->
  <ion-tab icon-off="ion-calendar" icon-on="ion-calendar" href="#/tab/calendar">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-calendar"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

In calendar tab I have html option as follows:

```
<select ng-options="x for x in $ctrl.startTimes"></select>
```

When the select menu opens, the view scroll to upward and creates empty space under `ion-tabs`.

How can I move the view to initial position as before the select menu opens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I able to find one workaround solution, It still have some minor issue. To solve it I do the following:

**First:** In app.js I disable the scroll as follows:

```
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

}
```

**Second:** Register the keypad hide event, it will fire `keyboardHideHandler` when keypad or select control close:

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', keyboardHideHandler);
```

**Third:** Implement `keyboardHideHandler` as follows. After implementing all the issue occurred only first time, so you have to use the flag `isFirstTimeEdit`:

```
var isFirstTimeEdit = true; 
function keyboardHideHandler(e){
      if(isFirstTimeEdit) {
        isFirstTimeEdit = false;

        if(window.scrollY >= 20) {
          document.body.style.marginTop = "20px";
        }
      }
      window.removeEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);
}
```